# Redirect to above directory PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, session-variables

I'm trying to redirect my app to another php page thats located above at the root folder of the project. I'm having issues saving my SESSION variable and i think this will solve it.

This is a very simple task i know but i'm very new this this so sorry if it's obvious.

I'm trying to avoid using http://../../../.. etc therefore im looking for a relative URL solution.

Please see current setup:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Correct!');
       window.location='http://localhost/testing/yourprofile.php';
       </script>";
        exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is how you normally go one level above    
window.location.href = '../';
```

But may I give you some advise? You should not need to redirect a user above the root directory. Yo will encounter a huge number of problems. Also your programs won't work on shared hosted Webservers.

Sometimes you may come up with an idea wich seems to work, but you can probably figure out a much easier solution. If you post more information about your question I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can return to the root by starting your path with `/`.

For this example, change `window.location='http://localhost/testing/yourprofile.php';` to `window.location.href='/testing/yourprofile.php';`